# jQuery - Can I combine object reference with other selectors?

Tags: jquery

Occasionally I pass an 'object' to jQuery rather than an id or other selectors. For example

```
<input type="text" onclick="doit(this)" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function doit(e) {
    var a = $(e).val();
}
```

It is useful when ids are not convenient such as long lists of elements or dynamically created input fields. I actually have seen any examples of passing the object. I just tried it and it works.

My question is: can I combine object selector with other selectors such as I would with ids. so instead of:

```
$("#myDiv .myClass").something()
```

I wouldn't know how to code it - something like this maybe:

```
$(e + " .myclass").something
```

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this:

```
$(e).find(".myclass").something();
```

or the slightly shorter, yet less efficient version:

```
$(".myclass", e).something();
```

The reason you can't use `+` is that your `e` is a DOM element, which is not a useful type for concatenation into a selector string, since you end up with something like:

```
"[object HTMLInputElement] .myclass"
```

Comment: thanks, I tried: $(e).find(".myclass").something(); and it works

Answer (score 2):

This is one way. using the [context parameter in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

```
$(".myclass", e).something();
```